# Will cassandra full compaction remove expired data in files generated by previous compaction?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a table TTL=10days in cassandra, I usually do full compaction on every Monday and Thursday.

I noticed that after compaction on Thursday, Cassandra did not touch/compact the files generated on Monday.

Why is that? Is that possible the file generated on Monday is too big? How can I fix it? BTW, I uses SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you do a "full compaction" what exactly are you doing to trigger this?

In general, SizeTieredCompaction will only compact a set number of similarly sized SSTables.  This means that if your table (table 1) from Monday is say size X MBs and you have min_threshold on the table set to 4 then it would require 4 tables of ~X Mbs before the table 1 would be compacted again.  This means that if you say generate a new compacted table of ~ X MBs every 3 days it would take 9 days before the original table was compacted again.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer. What I meant "full compaction" is I ran "nodetool compact". "nodetool compact" usually generated a single very big file. When I ran "nodetool compact" some days later, if the file generated by "nodetool compact" is too big, it will cause "no suffice disk" exception, and ignore it.

Comment: Yes I was answering what happens when a scheduled compaction runs or what happens when you run nodetool compact with a table specified (minor compaction).  When you run it as you specified it will require you to have enough disk space to write a new file containing all your data as it compacts all SSTables into a single new SSTable.  It sounds like you did not have sufficient disk space as you state and that is the root of your issue.